# PHP Ticketing software with time tracking

Tags: php, logging, time-management, ticket-system

Looking for an opensource ticketing software with time tracking feature to log hours. I have looked at a couple of webapps but I am specifically looking for a software that I can download and install and tweak. I have tried OSTicket but that requires a not-so-straightforward tweak to log hours. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use [GLPI](http://www.glpi-project.org/?lang=en,) as it hooks neatly into a software and hardware inventory tool called [Ocsinventory](http://www.ocsinventory-ng.org/en/) and it may be worth a look as it already includes time tracking.

Two others in the same field and that include time management are: [Request Tracker](http://bestpractical.com/rt/) and [OTRS](http://otrs.org/)

Comment: thank you. request tracker has a good feature set will try it out.